# How to skip to a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I skip to cell D14 when D10 is filled?

I am trying to input a timestamp, when I click a button, into cell D14 after cell D10 has been filled. Is this possible? I have tried (r == 10, 'D14') but it did not work. I have tried to write a skipTo function that did not work, and I tried reading the Google Sheets Help page but I could not find a solution. Please help..!

This is what I have so far:

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

function getNextRow1() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var r = 4; r <= 10; r++); {
    if (sheet.getRange("D" + r).isBlank()) {
      return r;
      }   
    }
  }

function getNextRow2() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var r = 4; r <= 10; r++) {
    if (sheet.getRange("E" + r).isBlank()) {
      return r;
    }
  }
}


function addRecord1(d,) {
  var row = getNextRow1();
  setValue('D' + row, d);
}

function addRecord2(e,) {
  var row = getNextRow2();
  setValue('E' + row, e);
}

function btn_start() {
  addRecord1(new Date());
}

function btn_stop() {
  addRecord2(new Date());
}
```

[image]

Comment: No language tag, no specific question, very little information. Please [edit] your post to make it more clear about a) what this is that you posted; and b) a clearly stated problem description; and c) ask a specific question related to the code you've posted.

Comment: Hello, did Cooper answer solved your question? Could you maybe share a sample of your sheet? From what you say it seems as easy as checking if the value is already written and shifting the range.

Comment: @Raserhin No Cooper did not answer my question. I have a sample of my sheet above. I don't know how to shift the range if the value is written.

Comment: How many weeks do you have to do this for? Is it only week 1 and week 2?

Comment: Yes just the 2 weeks...

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.range.rowStart==10 && e.value) {
    sh.getRange('D14').activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper - I noticed your answer ended up in review queue - could you please add a line or two of explanation despite the code is self-explanatory enough?

Comment: Hi Cooper, I don't understand the code. I tried it and it did not work for me. How am I suppose to activate the code? Should I just code it in anywhere? Please explain.

Comment: It runs from a simple trigger read about them in the documentation. They can be found in the guide section and read about the event objects as well. This particular one runs whenever a user performs a manual edit on a range. The parameter e is loaded with the event object which provides some valuable information. Learn how to use it wisely. You be thankful that you did.

Comment: I am not doing a manual edit. I am clicking a button to insert a timestamp. Thank you for the information though, I will try and read about it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Make make a check if `r - 1` is a multiple of 10 and if it is, `+3`. Do this for two weeks.*

#### Code example:

```
function getNextRow1() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var r = 4; r <= 20; r++); {

    if ((r - 1) % 10) == 0) r =+ 3;

    if (sheet.getRange("D" + r).isBlank()) {
      return r;
    }   
  }
}
```